# Why is the move constructor not called when moving in a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, move-semantics

I am trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <utility>

struct C2 {
        C2() = default;
        C2(C2 const&) = delete;
        C2(C2&&) = default;
};

int main() {
        C2 p2;
        ([p2_1{ std::move(p2) }]() {
                auto p2_2 = std::move(p2_1); // <---
        })();
        return 0;
}
```

However, this doesn't compile and gives an error that the assignment to `p2_2` is calling a deleted function, namely the copy constructor. Note that the move to `p2_1` is fine. Why is this not using the move constructor?

Comment: I'm no lambda expert, but instead of moving `p2` into `p2_1`, capturing `p2_1`, and then moving `p2_1` into `p2_2`, why not just [capture `p2` by reference and move it directly to `p2_2`](http://ideone.com/PsBQMJ)? `[&p2]() { auto p2_2 = std::move(p2); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is a much stripped down version of what I was actually doing. I kept removing parts until I got a small sample that still has the problem. The actual code needed the lambda to outlive the function scope in which it was declared, so capture-by-ref was not an option.

Comment: OK, that makes sense then.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The catch here is that the `operator()` of the anonymous class type the lambda represents is `const` by default.  That means you can't move from `p2_1` since the `this` of the lambda is `const&` in the function.  What you need to do is use the `mutable` keyword like

```
int main() {
        C2 p2;
        ([p2_1{ std::move(p2) }]() mutable {
                auto p2_2 = std::move(p2_1); // <---
        })();
        return 0;
}
```

Which makes the function non const which in turn means you can mutate its members.  This allows you to move `p2_1` instead of trying to copy it.

Comment: Does this apply to capturing `this`, too? I seem to be able to call non-const functions using a captured `this` pointer

Comment: @baruch That is a good question.  AFAIK when you capture `this` it keeps its value type so if it is non const then it will be non const in the lambda.

Comment: @baruch `this` is const but `*this` is not. It is a const pointer but not a pointer-to-const.

Comment: @baruch: Notice that the `this` in NathanOliver's answer is very different from what you get by capturing `this`! When NathanOliver says "since its `this` is `const&`, he's talking about a pointer to *the closure object itself.* But if you actually typed the keyword `this` inside the body of the lambda, you wouldn't get a pointer to the closure object; you'd get (and capture, by value) a pointer to *the object whose member function lexically encloses the lambda-expression.* It is impossible in C++ to name the entity Nathan is talking about, unless you use something like the Y combinator.